# Set and its complement that are both dense

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I'm trying to use Baire's theorem to give an example about open sets $\left\{X_i:i\in N\right\}$ in $\Bbb R$ such that $\cap_{i\in N} X_i$ and $\Bbb R - \cap_{i\in N} X_i$ are dense in $\Bbb R$. So far I'm still unsuccessful, since $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb R-\Bbb Q$ both satisfy the dense property, but $\Bbb Q$ cannot be the intersection of open sets in $\Bbb R$. Can anyone please give help me with this problem?

Comment: You mean that $\Bbb Q$ is not the intersection of *countably many* open sets in $\Bbb R$. But $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$ *is* the intersection of countably many open sets, and that’s all you need.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: thank you very much for your help. If that's the case, what should the explicit form for each OPEN sets $X_i$ be so that the intersection of those countably many open sets are $R-Q$?

Comment: To keep this off the unanswered list, I posted my response as an answer; feel free to ask if you still have any questions about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $q\in\Bbb Q$ let $U_q=\Bbb R\setminus\{q\}$; then $\bigcap_{q\in\Bbb Q}U_q=\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$, which is dense in $\Bbb R$, and the complement of this intersection is $\Bbb Q$, which is also dense in $\Bbb R$. $\Bbb Q$ is countable, so you can re-index the sets $U_q$ with natural numbers if you wish.

Comment: Many thanks for your great help.

Comment: @user177196: You’re very welcome.